# Filtering items in array based on subarray

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm working on sorting an array of items with ng-repeat. It's just an old fashioned alphabetical sorting, so orderBy should do me fine. However, the twist is that the name of the item is in an array contained inside the item (and legacy code dictates that it stays this way). So my HTML would look something like this:

```
<ul>
     <li data-ng-repeat="item in itemList | orderBy: 'item.name[0]'">
...
```

But I can't for the life of me make Angular (v1.2.5) access the value in that array, regardless of what I try. Is there a way of doing this without venturing into workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in itemList | orderBy:'name'>
```

And if this does not help. please provide a plunkr, also containing some data.